# how to use python upload a local file on HDFS with hdfs3 lib

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to upload a local file on HDFS using python script. Right now, I have Hue(username and password), my ip address. I wanna use hdfs3 lib from python. I basically know how to automate this process. I can find the location I intend to upload on HDFS using Hue(run some query).

My question is where I can find this host,port information and connect to HDFS.

```
from hdfs3 import HDFileSystem

hdfs = HDFileSystem(host=***, port=***)
```

Answer (score 0):

Those would be the namenode address and port.

Ask your cluster administrator for that information. Or, if you are a Hue admin, you might be able to get that information from Configuration page

Note: You could also shell out to `hdfs dfs -put` if that works on the same machine as the python script

Comment: A follow up. 1. Every namenode corresponds a cluster of computers which has a specific address and port, correct? 2. if the program pass the line of code hdfs = HDFileSystem(host=***, port=***)， it generally means we connect to hdfs and we can upload something on it, but it does not need authorization? Like the username and password on Hue? Thanks

Comment: NameNode is the single address for HDFS cluster. Username on Hue is not directly related to the user accounts on HDFS, depending on the authorization methods, but sometimes NameNode does need user authentication